# How to put Grafana into maintenance mode?

Tags: devops, grafana, sre

Is there any way to put Grafana in maintenance mode? I want to show the details of the planned maintenance window in the Grafana UI for all the users. How can we do it?

Where we can show text like below

```
The Observabality plantform will be on maintaince from Friday 1 AM to 3 3 AM. The application may be slow...etc.
```